# Multiple buttons with same classname

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have 3 buttons with same classnames How I should click for example 2nd button?

`<div class="css-gvi9bl-control">…</div>`

Comment: Use [XPATH](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Comment: I have tried it

Comment: what text is inside the ```div```?

Comment: Its hard to show. so  if you can just check yourself.  [link](https://discord.com/register)  I want to know how to click on month, day and year...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:
`driver.find_elements_by_class_name('css-gvi9bl-control')[1].click()`

Alternatively:
`driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.css-gvi9bl-control')[1].click()`

Personally, I would use XPATH, but if you *really* want to use classname, css selector.

Comment: Possibly within the alternative instead of `find_element*` you meant **`find_elements*`**